# Why does fprintf command display >> in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, printf

Here is a sample of a random script in MATLAB.

```
prompt = 'Please enter a lowercase x:  ';
str = input(prompt, 's');
if str == 'x'
else
    fprintf('Error, you did not enter a lowercase x.')
end
```

This always display what I have in the fprintf command with a >> at the end of it in the command window. For example, in this random context it would display ...

```
Error, you did not enter a lowercase x.>>
```

Simple question, yet I'm new to MATLAB. Why do I get a >> at the end of every fprintf command? Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: To add to the already posted answers: note that `if str == 'x'` may not be doing what you expect. It will _not_ run the `fprintf` statement if you enter for example `xx`. That's because `str == 'x'` compares _element-wise_, and `if` the condition is considered to be `true` if _all_ its components are `true`. See [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html)

Comment: and to further add to the answer, if you specify `2` as the `fprintf` output direction, your message will be written in red. ex: `fprintf(2,'Error: bla bla bla ...\n')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify a line-break in your string, so `fprintf` pushes the text to the command windows and spawns another input prompt (the `>>`) directly after the text.  Add a line break meta-character to the string (`\n`) to fix the issue:

```
fprintf('Error, you did not enter a lowercase x.\n')
```

Also, if your goal is to issue an error, you should use the [`error`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) function.  It halts execution of the code and colors the message red like other MATLAB errors.

Comment: That is exactly it. I see now how the code is read. I just used the code above as just a random code to display my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @amkas90 If you find any of the questions helpful, please up-vote, and if you asked the question, [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer "that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you."

Comment: Thanks. I would upvote, however, I am also knew to stackoverflow. Need 15 reputation points to up vote. Will do so very shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Here the `fprintf` simply displays the text and returns to command console.

Use newline `'\n'` character,

```
fprintf('Error, you did not enter a lowercase x.\n');
%                                               ~~~
```

to come back atfer newline with `>>` prompt